# How to prevent element from scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div container having 4 divs each of height 100vh so it makes the container of 400vh.

So, what I want is to stop the scrolling in that particular container while not making them hidden because I want to redirect to them one by one.

It's simply  like : .container{scroll: do nothing}

No problem with javascript as well...

Comment: `overflow: none;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];

parent.addEventListener('mousewheel',(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 300px;
}

.child{
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```